# Unable to login into site through RoboBrowser Python

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, robobrowser

I tried to login into the site through RoboBrowser but I'm facing below error.

```
import config
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
br = RoboBrowser()
br.open('https://stackoverflow.com')
form = br.get_form(id="login-form")
form['Email address']=config.username
form['Password']=config.password
br.submit_form(form)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\forms\form.py", line 216, in __setitem__
    self.fields[key].value = value
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 784, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Through any other module, we are able to login into site and search data in the next screen. Example if I login into site and next page it will display as "Hello User".
I want to bring the output and see "Hello User" is displayed or not through the python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to login to the sing up form. Move to the login page and then login.

```
import config
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

br = RoboBrowser()
br.open('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login')

form = br.get_form(id="login-form")
form['email']=config.username
form['password']=config.password
br.submit_form(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error, surprisingly, would happen if you are setting a form field which is not actually a part of the form. Tomasz's answer goes to the point of what was wrong, but a couple additional notes:

- `robobrowser` is not supported and you should look into better-maintained libraries like [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup) or [`mechanize`](https://pypi.org/project/mechanize/)
- [StackExchange has an API](https://api.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Let me check on those libraries